# How to leverage Assigned to equals to [Me] for a SP or O365 group

Tags: sharepoint-online, list-view, task-list, spgroup

I have a task list (SPonline OOTB) setup and in the AssignedTO people picker column i want to assign tasks to O365/SP Groups and not to a single user as that's the requirement.

The MY TASks view uses 'ASsignedTO' equal to [Me] to show tasks only to current logged in user but noticed if I use a people picker column that has Group names tagged then equal to [Me] does not work.

For example, I added a SP group called TestSP with members: Test A and Test B. In task list then I added a people picker column called 'GroupAssignedTo' that allow people and groups. Then I added a task with title 'TASK TEST' and set GroupAssignedTO as TestSP. When I log in either as user Test A and Test B , my tasks view does not show TASK TEST.

Can this be made to work somehow, thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Just found an answer here and it works great: https://wonderlaura.com/2013/06/19/the-my-groups-view/ , hope it helps someone.